# How to update in db2 with join

Tags: sql, database, db2, sql-update

I want to do an update, updating only the values affected, but my update query has a join, so `where exists` won't work.

```
update semester_workload tA
set tA.account = (SELECT DISTINCT (t2.WORKING - t2.WORKLOAD) FROM SEMESTER_WORKLOAD t1
        join SEMESTER_WORKLOAD t2 on t1.ID_LECTURER = t2.ID_LECTURER
        WHERE t2.ACADEMIC_SEMESTER = 'WS10' AND tA.ID_SW = t2.ID_SW);
where exists (SELECT 1 FROM SEMESTER_WORKLOAD t1        
        join SEMESTER_WORKLOAD t2 on t1.ID_LECTURER = t2.ID_LECTURER
        WHERE t2.ACADEMIC_SEMESTER = 'WS10' AND tA.ID_SW = t2.ID_SW);
```

This code won't work because apparently it does not recognize `where exists` after the join clause.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `distinct` is **NOT**  a function. The parentheses are useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's just a simple syntax error. You have an excess semi colon before your `where exists` clause:

```
update semester_workload tA
set tA.account = (SELECT DISTINCT (t2.WORKING - t2.WORKLOAD) FROM SEMESTER_WORKLOAD t1
        join SEMESTER_WORKLOAD t2 on t1.ID_LECTURER = t2.ID_LECTURER
        WHERE t2.ACADEMIC_SEMESTER = 'WS10' AND tA.ID_SW = t2.ID_SW) -- ; remove this
where exists (SELECT 1 FROM SEMESTER_WORKLOAD t1        
        join SEMESTER_WORKLOAD t2 on t1.ID_LECTURER = t2.ID_LECTURER
        WHERE t2.ACADEMIC_SEMESTER = 'WS10' AND tA.ID_SW = t2.ID_SW);
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a ";" In excess. Note that you do not need to join the same table three times, you can just do like this:

```
UPDATE SEMESTER_WORKLOAD t1
set t1.account = 
(
   SELECT t2.WORKING - t2.WORKLOAD FROM SEMESTER_WORKLOAD t2
   WHERE 
   (t1.ID_LECTURER, t1.ID_SW, 'WS10')=(t2.ID_LECTURER, t2.ID_SW, t2.ACADEMIC_SEMESTER) 
   FETCH FIRST ROWS ONLY
)
where exists 
(
   SELECT * FROM SEMESTER_WORKLOAD t2
   WHERE 
   (t1.ID_LECTURER, t1.ID_SW, 'WS10')=(t2.ID_LECTURER, t2.ID_SW, t2.ACADEMIC_SEMESTER) 
)
```